# How to avoid the 'ERROR: module.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform'?

Tags: python-3.x, linux-mint, python-wheel

I have following issue with my Python 3.11 installed from source on Linux Mint 18.4:

The installation from source was not able to find the SSL libraries so Python 3.11 was compiled and installed but does not support Internet access. Tweaking the installation procedure with providing a set of environment variables pointing to the installed Tcl/TK libraries I was able to install Python 3.11 with tkinter support, but haven't found yet a way to make the installation procedure finding the SSL libraries (the on Internet found solutions did not work or did not address the details of my system).

I don't see the lack of Internet access as a big problem, because I can work around it by installing with pip3.11 by Python 3.9 downloaded modules without downloading them again for Python 3.11. This works in most cases, but for some modules I am trying to install from downloaded wheels I am getting errors like for example this one below:

```
ERROR: mypy-1.0.1-cp39-cp39-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

The same wheel works with pip3.9 , but not with pip3.11.

What is the cause of the issue I am experiencing and what would be a  work-around it?

Comment: **1.** "*…haven't found yet a way to make the installation procedure finding the SSL libraries…*" To compile from sources you need development files including header files. **2.** "*…I can work around it by installing with pip3.11 by Python 3.9 downloaded modules…*" As you can see you cannot; binary wheels are incompatible between major Python versions because Python APIs are not fully compatible; you need to re-download everything for Python 3.11.

Comment: @phd the development files for SSL are there, but I haven't yet found a way which variables to which values I have to set or what to change in the setup files to make them visible to the 3.11 installation. And ... no, I don't need to re-download *everything* for Python 3.11. Almost all of the wheels downloaded by 3.9 work OK also for 3.11 .The mentioned one is one of the rare exceptions. By the way: the error message mentions "platform" not Python version. Hmmm... does "platform' mean the OS or the Python version?

Comment: "platform' means Python version + OS + processor architecture (x86 (32 bit), amd64 (still Intel), aarch64 (ARM), etc).

Comment: Where the limitations/restrictions about the Python version are stored in the wheel? I can't imagine that 3.11 will brake what works in 3.9 . Have mypy and numpy not already provided wheels for the 3.11 Python version? How can I know in advance the upper Python version a wheel does support? Is this always an issue and a reason for not upgrading too early (I was eager to check out 'match').

Answer (score 0):

"Binary wheel" is not the same as "wheel" in general.

There are wheels that contain binary Python extension modules that are written and compiled against a certain version of the Python ABI (application binary interface); those will not work across Python versions or Python interpreter implementations. In your example, the `cp39` part of the [compatibility tag](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/platform-compatibility-tags/) means "CPython 3.9"; `cp311` would be "CPython 3.11". (There's also a "stable version 3 ABI", `abi3`, but I haven't seen that used a lot.)

Wheels that don't contain any binary code can also be incompatible with interpreter major versions; a wheel that has Python 3 only code would be `py3`, and one that could work with both Python 2 and Python 3 would be `py2.py3` (though since Python 2 is EOL, these are increasingly rare).

Furthermore, a wheel's metadata may contain a field describing the range of specific Python versions it's compatible with in the `Python-Requires` field, e.g. `>=3.6`.

> Have mypy and numpy not already provided wheels for the 3.11 Python version?

Take a look: [numpy](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files), [mypy](https://pypi.org/project/mypy/#files).

You can find the compatibility tags your version of Python supports with `pip debug --verbose` – or you can just `pip download --only-binary=:all: numpy mypy` to have Pip download the wheels for the given packages and their dependencies.

> How can I know in advance the upper Python version a wheel does support?

Broadly by looking at the filename with the above guidance.

> Is this always an issue and a reason for not upgrading too early?

There's no reason why you couldn't have multiple versions of Python on your machine; virtualenvs, too, are version-specific anyway. If some libraries you need don't support a new Python, use them with an older Python.

Comment: Thanks for your response and the effort to write a (late) answer. In between I have managed to convince Python 3.11.2 to compile with tkinter and css support on Linux Mint 21 by editing the `/etc/ld.so.conf` and downloading some missing libraries along with their `dev` versions. It was a loooong way to put it all together and make it work. I am still a little bit confused not being sure what exactly was really necessary and what not. And after a download of the 3.11 wheel versions I  have got also numpy, scipy and some other ones which resisted installation before installed.

Comment: I hope you didn't install Python entirely by hand – [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) will do that for you. Also, editing ld.so.conf is probably not a good idea...

Comment: With paths which can not be found by the compiler I see no chance to get Python 3.11 installed on Mint 21 without some preliminary adjustments that are 'not a good idea". The work around would be to use Python 3.10.6 with tkinter and ssl Mint 21 comes with. And yes ... compiling Python takes time ... on my machine almost an hour, but ... there are no binary packages there to use. Anyway I prefer installation from source giving me the chance to tweak the source or at least take a look at them knowing that they are actually what I run.

Comment: `pyenv` installs from source. In any case, provided you have the tk and ssl dev packages installed, you really do _not_ need to adjust the ld configuration.

Comment: My philosophy is to avoid to most possible extent any level of indirection. pyenv would be then just one more tool to take care about ... python alone gives already enough trouble and grows and grows in size instead of shrinking. Multiple versions ... because storage is so cheap? Multiple versions == multiple potential sources of trouble. I have a Python3.11.2 binary placed where the system python3 is and named it just python. So with `python` I have access to it and all of its libraries installed. Used altinstall - this should be enough to get it run on its own.

Comment: For example a 3.9 wheel version may be also suitable for python 3.11 without any changes. So the not answered part of my question is how to install a module from a 3.9 wheel on python 3.11 working around a maybe unnecessary limitation of validity of a wheel imposed by pip.

Comment: _May_ be suitable, but if the tag in the filename says it's not, you're playing with fire and have taken the safeties off. You're free to rename the wheel to match one of the tags supported by your installation, keeping the aforementioned in mind - if anything breaks or sets your machine on fire, it's on you.